# Graphing indeterminate form functions

Tags: calculus, limits, graphing-functions

For example, this limit:
$$\lim_{x→0}(\frac{x}{{1-e}^{x}})$$

According to l'Hôpital's rule, it is an indeterminate form thus the solution of the above equation is -1.

However, when the function
$$f(x)= \frac{x}{{1-e}^{x}}$$
is graphed, it appears to pass through the point (0,-1)as follows

[The graph of f(x)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZvI8.png)

The problem is when x = 0 is substituted into f(x), it will give $\frac{0}{0}$ which is mathematically undefined.

But why does the graph have a solution to f(0)?
Why does a graph have solution to indeterminate forms?

Comment: Did you mean to write $\frac{x}{1-e^x}$?

Comment: Yes, it is x power of e. Sorry, I didn't check the spelling and formatting carefully before publishing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By L’Hôpital’s Rule, the limit is: $$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{1-e^x}= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{-e^x}=-1.$$

Now, as you will see from the graph, both the Left and Right-Hand limits will approach -1 as x approaches 0. However, at x=0, the function is undefined. [image]

Comment: I used Grapher app from Apple and I didn't realise that it doesn't show any undefined points on the graph.